# How to navigate to another window using Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

So, I am making a small Program, the user interface is simple, the user clicks a button to move to the other window, here is the code for the Main Window
.cs

```
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace AvaloniaProgram
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void goToWindow2()
        {
            //on click go to the 2nd window
        }
    }


}
```

AXAML code:

```
<Grid
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="AvaloniaProgram.MainWindow"
    Height="400" Width="400"
    Title="AvaloniaProgram">

    <Grid>
            
            <Button 
                Content="Window2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="10"
                Command="{Binding GoToWindow2}"/>
            
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I want to learn more about Avalonia, in Android we just do this for example:

```
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_another_activity"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="75sp"
                    android:onClick="goToOtherActivity"
                    android:text="Other Activity" />
```

```
        val GoToOtherActivityButton = findViewById<Button>(R.button_another_activity)

        GoToOtherActivityButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(this@MainMenuActivity, OtherActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        })
```

How to do something similar in Avalonia ?

Comment: Mobile and desktop are two very different beasts. What you describe in Android is navigating to another `VIEW`, not `Window`. First question is why do you have multiple `Windows` and is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

As Mobile and Desktop have different approaches, Your question is incorrect in fact. I invite you to use this library https://github.com/AvaloniaInside/Shell

Shell, helps you to solve the complexity of navigation and application lifecycle.